# Converting query results into DataFrame in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, psycopg2

I am trying to perform manipulation on the result from a query using psycog2. Thus I have to covert result into pandas DataFrame. But when i use the following code and print, only the columns name are printed not the rows. I used 'pd.DataFrame.from_records' too but that did not work.

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
conn_string = "Connect_Info"
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
rows=pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=['page_num','Frequency'])

for row in rows:
   print row

conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

The result of cursor.fetchall() -

```
(1L, 90990L)
(3L, 6532L)
(2L, 5614L)
(4L, 4016L)
(5L, 2098L)
(6L, 1651L)
(7L, 1158L)
(8L, 854L)
(9L, 658L)
(10L, 494L)
(11L, 345L)
(12L, 301L)
(13L, 221L)
(15L, 152L)
(14L, 138L)
(16L, 113L)
(17L, 93L)
(18L, 73L)
(20L, 62L)
(19L, 55L)
(22L, 44L)
(21L, 35L)
(23L, 29L)
(25L, 24L)
(27L, 19L)
(26L, 18L)
```

Comment: can you put here the result of cursor.fetchall()?

Comment: can you print the output of cursor.fetchall()? Also not sure you can iterate through DataFrame this way

Comment: The iterable returned from a df are the columns not the rows

Comment: Note 1: for fetching the data, you can better use `read_sql_query`, then all the above becomes almost a one-liner (see my answer).

Comment: Note 2: can you clarify what kind of manipulation you want to do? Iterating manually over the rows of a DataFrame is not very efficient, *and* in most cases it is not needed (most manipulations can be done with vectorised methods).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly what should happen when you iterate over a dataframe, you see the column names. If you want to see the df just print the df. To see the rows:

```
for ind, row in df.iterrows(): 
    print(row.values)
```

Or .values:

```
for row in df.values:
   print(row)
```

Comment: Technically a tuple consisting of (index, Series) is returned from [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) so if you wanted just the row values then `for index, row in df.iterrows(): print(row)` would be better

Comment: @maggs the row is in fact a `Series` so you get the value with the column name, if you wanted just the values then `print(row.values)` will give you what you want

Answer (score 11):

Maybe not directly an answer on your question, but you should use `read_sql_query` for this instead doing the fetchall and wrap in DataFrame yourself. This would look like:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
rows = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

instead of all your code above.

And for your actual question, see http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#iteration for an explanation and the different options.
The basics is that iterating over a dataframe, iterates over the column names. To iterate over the rows you can use other functions like `.iterrows()` and `.itertuples()`. But remember, in most cases iterating manually over the rows is not needed.

Comment: I am learning postgress and python. I have to make a system that will involve a number of queries for different modules. For this question, i am trying to make a histogram with x axis as column 1 and y as column 2 of the query result.

Answer (score 0):

another suggestion is using itertuples, which yields (index, row_value1, row_value2...) tuples.

```
for tup in rows.itertuples():
    print tup

'(0, 1, 90990)
(1, 3, 6532)
(2, 2, 5614)
(3, 4, 4016)
...'
```

as you can see the first position is the index, the socend is the value of the first column and the second is the value of the second column.