# Convert psycopg2 DictRow query to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, psycopg2

I would like to convert a [psycopg2 `DictRow`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#dictionary-like-cursor) query to a pandas dataframe, but pandas keeps complaining:

```
curs = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
data = curs.fetchall()

print type(data)
print pd.DataFrame(list(data))
```

However, I always get an error although I specifically passed a `list`???

```
<type 'list'>
TypeError: Expected list, got DictRow
```

The result is the same if I do `pd.DataFrame(data)` Could someone please help me make this work?

It would also be nice if the column names of the dataframe worked (i.e. extract `DictRow` and pass them to the dataframe).

**Update:**
Since I need to process the data, I would like to use the data from the psycopg2 query as is and not the [pandas approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474021/2075003), e.g. [`read_sql_query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html).

Comment: Opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/14169

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, I eventually found this hacky solution:

```
print pd.DataFrame([i.copy() for i in data])
```

The `copy()` function of the `DictRow` class will return an actual dictionary. With the list comprehension I create a list of (identical) dictionaries, that Pandas will happily accept.

I am still puzzled why `list(data)` produced a `TypeError`. Maybe someone can still enlighten me.

Comment: because the rows are `psycopg2.DictType` you can see my answer below

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: `pandas.read_sql_query()` is a more elegant way to read a SQL query into a dataframe, without the need for `psycopg2`. See the [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html).

I've been having the same issue. The easiest way I found was to convert the DictRow to a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
curs = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
data = curs.fetchall()

print type(data)
print pd.DataFrame(np.array(data))
```

If you want to get the column names, you can access them as the keys for each row of the `DictRow`. However, converting to a numpy array doesn't preserve the order. So one (inelegant) way is as follows:

```
curs = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")
data = curs.fetchall()

print type(data)
colNames = data[0].keys()
print pd.DataFrame([[row[col] for col in colNames] for row in data], columns=colNames)
```

Comment: `pandas.read_sql_query` is more elegant indeed, but your solution here is preferable for those who might not want to create a dependency on `sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 2):

You indeed need to parse out the elements first. You might be confused because the whole result is a list of `DictRow` elements, but element is not a list. Hence in `pandas 0.22.0` even reading `from_records` wont not work straight away.

This works fine with native types:

```
inp = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}, {'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(inp)
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  2.0
2  1.0  NaN
3  NaN  2.0
4  1.0  NaN
5  NaN  2.0
```

But printing the results of Psycopg2 query is probably the source of confusion (own data):

`[[157, 158, 83, 1], [157, 159, 47, 1], [158, 157, 53, 1], [158, 159, 38, 1], [159, 157, 76, 1], [159, 158, 24, 1]] <class 'list'>` but in fact the first element `[157, 158, 83, 1] <class 'psycopg2.extras.DictRow'>`